# How to use bash/miller to add a +/- diff column to identify CSV file differences?

Tags: bash, csv, miller

I have some data files for which I'd like to generate a "diff" column, meaning add a column that indicates whether a particular line has been added/removed from the current file. For example, I have the following two files, `a.csv`:

```
id,data,data2
1,A,B
2,A,B
3,A,B
4,A,B
```

and `b.csv`:

```
id,data,data2
2,A,C
3,A,C
4,A,C
5,A,C
```

I'd like to only compare based on the `id` whether a row has been added/removed. The data does not matter. The best I've come up with so far is to use [miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) in the following manner:

```
#!/bin/bash

t1=$(mktemp)
t2=$(mktemp)
t3=$(mktemp)

mlr --icsv --ocsv put '$diff = "-"' then reorder -f diff a.csv > "$t1"
mlr --icsv --ocsv put '$diff = "+"' then reorder -f diff b.csv > "$t2"
mlr --icsv --ocsv join -f "$t1" -j id --ul --ur --np then unsparsify "$t2" > "$t3"
mlr --icsv --ocsv join -f "$t3" -j id --ul --ur      then unsparsify then reorder -f diff,id then sort -nf id b.csv

rm "$t1"
rm "$t2"
rm "$t3"
```

This generates the following, which is what I want:

```
diff,id,data,data2
-,1,A,B
,2,A,C
,3,A,C
,4,A,C
+,5,A,C
```

The unfortunate aspect of this solution is that it needs run miller four times and makes use of three temporary files. Miller doesn't seem to work with bash process substitution (the `<()` business).

Is there a more direct way of generating this kind of output?

Comment: You could `cut -f1 -d','` on each file and then pipe to `diff`?

Comment: @jeremysprofile Thanks, but then I would not end up with a CSV output file that I need to do further processing.

Comment: What about a `join` to get all the data in a single file and an `awk` to do the comparisons and write the needed format?

Comment: @Poshi That would result in fewer invocations but it would basically result in my writing a program to do it, which I could then do in any language. I was looking for a tool that would just do it easily.

Comment: You are right. But when the code is so easy and the tool does not exist, using what's available could be overkill, as is the case. In fact, by using miller, you are also coding a program yourself: you are telling miller to do lots of ordered operations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specialized tool: https://github.com/paulfitz/daff.

If you run in example daff a.csv b.csv you obtain

`---,1 ,A   ,B
→  ,2 ,A   ,B→C
→  ,3 ,A   ,B→C
→  ,4 ,A   ,B→C
+++,5 ,A   ,C`

Answer (score 0):

The following outputs exactly the same you posted:

```
join -t, -11 -22 <(
        # the order of files here is important
        # filter out duplicates too
        sort -t, -u -k1,1 b.csv a.csv
    ) <(
        comm --output-delimiter=, <(
                <a.csv \
                cut -d, -f1 |
                sort
            ) <(
                <b.csv \
                cut -d, -f1 |
                sort
            ) | 
        # this is stupid, but needs to be done anyway
        sed '
            s/^,,/,/;t;
            s/^,/+,/;t;
            s/^/-,/
        '
    ) |
awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, '{print $4,$1,$2,$3}'
```

But we can get way shorter with `join -o auto` and simple `awk`:

```
join -t, -11 -21  -a1 -a2 -o auto a.csv b.csv | 
awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, '{
    $6=""
    if (length($2) == 0) { $6="+"; $2=$4; $3=$5; }
    else if (length($4) == 0) { $6="-"; }
    else { $2=$4; $3=$5; }
    print $6,$1,$2,$3
}'
```

I have a strange feeling I would preserve `data2` column from both files with just, as they differ, and really simplify thinks, with just:

```
join -t, -11 -21  -a1 -a2 -o auto a.csv b.csv | 
awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, '{
    $6=""
    if (length($2) == 0) $6="+"
    if (length($4) == 0) $6="-"
    print $6,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5
}'
```

that outputs:

```
-,1,A,B,,
,2,A,B,A,C
,3,A,B,A,C
,4,A,B,A,C
+,5,,,A,C
```

that is interpreted as:

```
# diff, id, data from a.csv, data2 from a.csv, data from b.csv, data2 from b.csv
```

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/r5bvJS).